# Name order on CMS's add user block

Tags: drupal, contacts, fields

How can I change the sequence of first and last name field in the block, witch comes up on Drupal's "Add new user" page's bottom. Now the sequence is first_name *then* last_name, but I should have last_name *than* first_name.

Thank you.

Comment: Good question Pál

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the profile that is being used for registration by changing the weight of the field or using top/bottom arrows to change the order how they appear.

Navigate to Administer >> Customize Data and screens >> Profiles

Check the profile used for Drupal Registration and then click on the fields link besides it

[image]

Use the arrow button to change the order of the field.

[image]

You can also change the weight of the field by clicking on edit link of the field and then changing the order.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you! I don't know, why I didn't mentioned this admin page.

Comment: @PradeenNayak - This is a fantastic answer :-)